# Enable Cache while installing extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, cache, install

The custom for me has always been to totally disable the cache before installing any extensions.   Today I went to install an extension and discovered the installation instructions said,

> It’s required to enable cache in the administration panel of your site. Go to System/Cache Management. Choose all caches and take action “Enable” then submit.

I have never heard of Enabling Cache the first.

Is this the correct way to install an extension?

While the custom is to disable the cache (it seems obvious why), can someone elaborate on the ramifications of having the cache on/off while installing an extension?

Comment: Eh, wow. Guaranteed conflictville. I'd like a really good explanation from the developer as to why pre-install cache is necessary vs. "oh, your site will run better if you enable all cache post-install". Who is the developer?

Comment: It was written up like that within the installation guide for the store locator extn from magestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is always ***Turn off Cache whenever you are going to Make a change in Magento***

If your system is cached and then you installed your extension, then most probably system is not going to recognize that extension. It will detect new extension only after we cleared the cache after we installed the extension.

So if the extension documentation says so, then you have to contact the developer immediately and clarify on that point. If the developer shows any merits for enabling the cache, then feel free to put that as an answer here :)